# How can I make a Makefile notice the existence of a new file?

Tags: makefile

I want to use a Makefile to write a file `static/config.js` in the following manner:

- if `js/config_local.js` exists, copy it to `static/config.js`
- otherwise, copy `js/config.js` (which always exists) to `static/config.js`

So far, I have something that looks like this:

```
# If there's a config_local.js file, use that, otherwise use config.js
ifneq ($(wildcard js/config_local.js),)
config_file = js/config_local.js
else
config_file = js/config.js
endif

static/config.js: js/config.js js/config_local.js
    cp $(config_file) static/config.js

js/config_local.js:

clean:
    rm -f static/*
```

This mostly works, except that if there is no `js/config_local.js` file and I run `make`, and then I create a `js/config_local.js` file and run `make` again, it thinks it doesn't need to do anything.  I'm guessing that this is because of the empty `js/config_local.js` target in the Makefile, but if I remove that, then it can't build if the `js/config_local.js` file doesn't exist.

I also tried removing the empty `js/config_local.js` target and setting the dependencies of the `static/config.js` target to `js/*.js`, but that has the same problem of not noticing it needs to do something after I create the `js/config_local.js` file.

Comment: Use `$(config_file)` as the prereq also. But that won't help with your example scenario if `static/config.js` is newer than `js/config_local.js` since that's the point of what make does (avoids work it doesn't need to do again).

Comment: Also `config_file = $(word 1,$(wildcard js/config_local.js js/config.js))` will get you the first of whichever of those exist in one line.

Comment: @Etan - Adding `$(config_file)` to the dependencies of `static/config.js` does not seem to change anything.

Comment: Not 'add'. Replace. Use the file you found as the prereq not both.

Comment: Oh (I don't know what you meant by "also" then).  But in that case, it fails to update `static/config.js` when I *remove* `js/config_local.js` (I guess because `static/config.js` is newer than `js/config.js`).

Comment: Sorry, I meant "You already use it in the recipe. Use it in the prereq also" but that was unclear. And yes, that's the problem with make avoiding work that doesn't need to be done already because of timestamps. If you *always* want one or the other file copied (even when they haven't changed and aren't newer) then you need something like RTLinuxSW's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make checks file times, not contents.  A .PHONY will always force the operation.  The downside is it always copies.  Use the -p switch to preserve the file time.

```
.PHONY: static/config.js
static/config.js : $(firstword $(wildcard js/config_local.js js/config.js))
cp -p $< $@
```

Comment: `.PHONY` is a poor choice if `static/config.js` is a prerequisite of any other targets. In that case a `FORCE` rule is better.

Comment: This seems to work, thanks!  @Etan - in my case the `static/config.js` target is a prerequisite of another target ... can you explain why that would make `.PHONY` a bad choice?

Comment: From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets): "A phony target should not be a prerequisite of a real target file; if it is, its recipe will be run every time make goes to update that file." Essentially, the `.PHONY`-ness bleeds through to everything in the chain and you will re-run many more recipes than you expect even when the file ends up not changing at all (or remaining older than the other files). That being said if you are doing the copy you probably *want* the other targets to be run also (possibly) which just complicates things.

Comment: Well ideally I would want some way for it to know in what cases it should actually do the copy, but it sounds like this is impossible because all it can check are file times.  So it's called "phony" but in some sense it's the opposite of phony, since what it's doing is ensuring that the target *always* gets created (it seems like a more standard use of .PHONY is to pretend a target gets created when actually there is no such file?).  In my case I think it doesn't matter whether it causes the other targets to be run, so it should be okay.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Avril What are your desired criteria for when it should copy? Can you articulate them? There are ways to "trick" make into doing more than just this if you can clearly indicate what you want it to do.

Comment: It should copy iff either of the following conditions is true: (1) `js/config_local.js` does not exist and the contents of `js/config.js` are different from the contents of `static/config.js` (this condition happens when `js/config.js` gets modified or when `js/config_local.js` gets deleted), or (2) `js/config_local.js` does exist and the contents of `js/config_local.js` are different from the contents of `static/config.js` (this condition happens when `js/config_local.js` gets modified or created).